Type of function names [Function(nameof(classname)] and [Function("classname")]
Type of function names
[Function(nameof(classname)]  and [Function("classname")]
what is the difference between these two and
why we need to use this ,because we already have the function name by using the syntax , then why we use the decalaration of function name again
Example
public void name(){} 
and 
[Function(nameof(name)]
public void name(){}

What is the difference
difference with example

This question is similar to: What is the purpose of nameof?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also, [Function(nameof("classname"))] is just hilarious!

public void name(){} 

This is a normal C# function. You want this.
[Function(nameof(name)]
public void name(){}

This is a normal C# function. It is also annotated with a FunctionAttribute (See documentation) to let an OR-Mapper (Explanation) know that this function should be mapped to a database function of the name given to the FunctionAttribute.
If you don't know what that means, don't bother. You won't need it until long after you have learned about all those buzzwords.
